# Triple jquery animation & simultaneous responses

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

The title of the question might be confusing so I'm going to analyze what I mean. What I need to do is the combination of the following:

- 5 elements, working similar to star rating functionality: each time one is clicked, all previous elements change color (I've done this by animating the width of a background div).
- 5 elements, almost the same as above, but with different design. The functionality is the same, except for the width of each element which varies.
- 5 elements slideshow with previous/next pager. Both pagers should show number of previous/next slide & some text related to the previous/next slide.

I've built all these three and they work. But what I have trouble on doing is combining all them. For example, clicking on the 3rd element of the first "plugin" should trigger the other two plugins in the same way (ie for the second plugin, the background width animates to the 3rd element and for the third plugin, the slider goes to the 3rd slide with all related information, pagers' number & text changing properly).

I don't have access to the code I'm working on right now but also I wouldn't like to ask anyone to write so much code for my question.

**UPDATE**: Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weborion/3S4WG/5/.
Also, @Moby's Stunt Double: Why is this part necessary:
    function doThis(callback) {

```
// Initialise your schtick

// fire off the callback
if (typeof callback === "function") {
    callback();
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like all you're missing is a callBack within each plugin to chain the events upon each other at the correct times.

Comment: Isn't this going to start the other 2 animations after the 1st one is completed? I want all three to run at the same time.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can fire the callback at any point in the code of each of the plugins. Adding an answer...

Comment: The if statement is necessary because you might generate an exception if you try to execute null if the pointer to the callback was erroneous or if null was passed accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using callbacks:

```
function doThis(callback) {

    // Initialise your schtick

    // fire off the callback
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }

    // some more schlep and tickle here

}

function doThat(callBack) {
    // We'll fiddle-fart around here once the previous schtick is complete.

    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }

    // Then finish out this particular animation

}

function doTheOther() {
    // And finally we'll bring the madness to a halt.
}

doThis(doThat(doTheOther));
```

Comment: In order to make it more specific, I've updated my question with a jsfiddle. Any suggestions are welcome.